# Need to show user prompt as accept in ultraVNC Here is the scenario

Tags: vnc, ultravnc

Here is the scenario,

I am planning to implement remote control via ultraVNC, I have installed VNC in both the computers. I am able to connect to the user computer without the user accepting the request. Is there a version where we can enable a prompt for the user so that the user accepts the connection.

Comment: Did you check the configuration of UltraVNC?

Comment: It worked, I found the solution. http://forum.ultravnc.info/viewtopic.php?t=6323

Comment: So it was part of the configuration/documentation.